# Bluetoothctl always prompting for pairing even on trusted devices after Bullseye Upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I recently upgraded from `Debian Buster` to `Bullseye` and my Bluetooth mouse wont autoconnect despite having it paired and trusted. It always does connect but it doesn't pair it prompts for it such as.

```
$ bluetoothctl
[agent] Accept pairing (yes/no): [CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:E1:05:C2 ServicesResolved: yes
[agent] Accept pairing (yes/no):
```

Just printing out below the info of the whole situation see if you can tell anything I am doing wrong

```
$ bluetoothctl show
Controller 48:45:20:91:55:27 (public)
        Name: ux303u
        Alias: ux303u
        Class: 0x002c010c
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

[bluetooth]# info ED:8E:0E:E1:05:C2
Device ED:8E:0E:E1:05:C2 (random)
        Name: RAPOO BT4.0 MS
        Alias: RAPOO BT4.0 MS
        Appearance: 0x03c2
        Icon: input-mouse
        Paired: no
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        WakeAllowed: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1235pAA22d0001
```

```
$ cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

[General]

# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ', if Name is not set here and plugin 'hostname' is not loaded.
# The plugin 'hostname' is loaded by default and overides the Name set here so
# consider modifying /etc/machine-info with variable PRETTY_HOSTNAME=<NewName> instead.
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# Always allow pairing even if there are no agent registered
# Possible values: true, false
# Default: false
#AlwaysPairable = false

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
#PairableTimeout = 0

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. For BR/EDR this option is really only needed for qualification since the
# BITE tester doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases, for LE
# this disables the GATT client functionally so it can be used in system which
# can only operate as peripheral.
# Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
#NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
#DebugKeys = false

# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual

# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
#MultiProfile = off

# Permanently enables the Fast Connectable setting for adapters that
# support it. When enabled other devices can connect faster to us,
# however the tradeoff is increased power consumptions. This feature
# will fully work only on kernel version 4.1 and newer. Defaults to
# 'false'.
#FastConnectable = false

# Default privacy setting.
# Enables use of private address.
# Possible values: "off", "device", "network"
# "network" option not supported currently
# Defaults to "off"
# Privacy = off

# Specify the policy to the JUST-WORKS repairing initiated by peer
# Possible values: "never", "confirm", "always"
# Defaults to "never"
#JustWorksRepairing = never

# How long to keep temporary devices around
# The value is in seconds. Default is 30.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. never keep temporary devices
#TemporaryTimeout = 30

# Enables the device to issue an SDP request to update known services when
# profile is connected. Defaults to true.
#RefreshDiscovery = true

[Controller]
# The following values are used to load default adapter parameters.  BlueZ loads
# the values into the kernel before the adapter is powered if the kernel
# supports the MGMT_LOAD_DEFAULT_PARAMETERS command. If a value isn't provided,
# the kernel will be initialized to it's default value.  The actual value will
# vary based on the kernel version and thus aren't provided here.
# The Bluetooth Core Specification should be consulted for the meaning and valid
# domain of each of these values.

# BR/EDR Page scan activity configuration
#BRPageScanType=
#BRPageScanInterval=
#BRPageScanWindow=

# BR/EDR Inquiry scan activity configuration
#BRInquiryScanType=
#BRInquiryScanInterval=
#BRInquiryScanWindow=

# BR/EDR Link supervision timeout
#BRLinkSupervisionTimeout=

# BR/EDR Page Timeout
#BRPageTimeout=

# BR/EDR Sniff Intervals
#BRMinSniffInterval=
#BRMaxSniffInterval=

# LE advertisement interval (used for legacy advertisement interface only)
#LEMinAdvertisementInterval=
#LEMaxAdvertisementInterval=
#LEMultiAdvertisementRotationInterval=

# LE scanning parameters used for passive scanning supporting auto connect
# scenarios
#LEScanIntervalAutoConnect=
#LEScanWindowAutoConnect=

# LE scanning parameters used for passive scanning supporting wake from suspend
# scenarios
#LEScanIntervalSuspend=
#LEScanWindowSuspend=

# LE scanning parameters used for active scanning supporting discovery
# proceedure
#LEScanIntervalDiscovery=
#LEScanWindowDiscovery=

# LE scanning parameters used for passive scanning supporting the advertisement
# monitor Apis
#LEScanIntervalAdvMonitor=
#LEScanWindowAdvMonitor=

# LE scanning parameters used for connection establishment.
#LEScanIntervalConnect=
#LEScanWindowConnect=

# LE default connection parameters.  These values are superceeded by any
# specific values provided via the Load Connection Parameters interface
#LEMinConnectionInterval=
#LEMaxConnectionInterval=
#LEConnectionLatency=
#LEConnectionSupervisionTimeout=
#LEAutoconnecttimeout=

[GATT]
# GATT attribute cache.
# Possible values:
# always: Always cache attributes even for devices not paired, this is
# recommended as it is best for interoperability, with more consistent
# reconnection times and enables proper tracking of notifications for all
# devices.
# yes: Only cache attributes of paired devices.
# no: Never cache attributes
# Default: always
#Cache = always

# Minimum required Encryption Key Size for accessing secured characteristics.
# Possible values: 0 and 7-16. 0 means don't care.
# Defaults to 0
#KeySize = 0

# Exchange MTU size.
# Possible values: 23-517
# Defaults to 517
#ExchangeMTU = 517

# Number of ATT channels
# Possible values: 1-5 (1 disables EATT)
# Default to 3
#Channels = 3

[Policy]
#
# The ReconnectUUIDs defines the set of remote services that should try
# to be reconnected to in case of a link loss (link supervision
# timeout). The policy plugin should contain a sane set of values by
# default, but this list can be overridden here. By setting the list to
# empty the reconnection feature gets disabled.
#ReconnectUUIDs=00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link
# lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
#ReconnectAttempts=7

# ReconnectIntervals define the set of intervals in seconds to use in between
# attempts.
# If the number of attempts defined in ReconnectAttempts is bigger than the
# set of intervals the last interval is repeated until the last attempt.
#ReconnectIntervals=1,2,4,8,16,32,64

# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
AutoEnable=true
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep tooth
[    3.512552] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.512574] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.512578] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.512579] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.512582] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.556746] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[    3.557920] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[    3.557924] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[    3.905734] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[    3.922991] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.922992] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.922995] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.923748] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel BT fw patch 0x32 completed & activated
[   13.505993] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.506015] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.506034] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```